# How do you prevent a jQuery UI Date Picker from giving the input focus when shown?

Tags: jquery-ui, focus, jquery-ui-datepicker

The default behavior of a jQuery date picker gives the input field focus when the date picker is shown. On a mobile device (e.g., iPhone), this behavior is undesirable because it slides up a keyboard and obscures the date picker.

I am currently working around this issue by disabling the input field when the date picker is shown and re-enabling it when closed. This works but seems less than ideal.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="start-date" class="date-input" />
<button id="start-date-calendar">Go</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".date-input").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        showCurrentAtPos: 1,
        stepMonths: 2,
        beforeShow: function (input, datePicker) {
            input.disabled = true;
        },
        onClose: function (dateText, datePicker) {
            this.disabled = false;
        }
    });
    $(".date-input").off();
    $("#start-date-calendar").click(function () {
        $('#start-date').datepicker("show");
    });
});
```

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FAq79/).

**Is it possible to stop the focus from happening directly?**

Comment: You can specify `date` as the value to the `type` attribute. However, this may not resolve your issue, as the JSFiddle shows the datepicker when the submit button is pressed, rather than when the field is focused on. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes, the intent is to display the date picker with a custom button rather than the default behavior of focusing the input (tap/click). Hence, I've unbound the handlers on the input field and added a show event to the button click. The API for using a custom button leaves a lot to be desired...